# I want to automate a process where I have to run truncate command with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am automating a process where I supposed to run the Linux commands like `ls`, `truncate` etc.

Well, I got stuck with `truncate` command where I take input from user and want to truncate an image.

`truncate` command will be

```
$ truncate -s <size> <image> in general. eg: #truncate -s 123456790 img_original.img.
```

I have below peace of code running:

```
import os
import subprocess
size= input('Please enter the size of the new image, in terms of Total Bytes =')
image= input("Enter the image file name =")
print(size)
print(image)
# expand the image to $size - truncate -s $size $image which will be new_image.
subprocess.call(["truncate", "--size",size,image] ,shell=True)
```

However, it is may seem very silly for experts but for me as beginner and new to python not sure why getting error like:

```
Please enter the size of the new image, in terms of Total Bytes =123
Enter the image file name ="kernel_a_c13.img"
123
kernel_a_c13.img
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testdev.py.txt", line 19, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["truncate", "--size",size,image] ,shell=True) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Well, now is there way to do above execution with other implementation in python or suggest me way to convert the both variables to same type. ( with typecasting if any).

Comment: use `subprocess.call(["truncate", "--size",str(size),str(image)] ,shell=True)`

Comment: I suppose you need `shell=False` for such invocation of `subprocess.call`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate first parameter into string **with `shell=True`**:

```
subprocess.call(" ".join(["truncate", "--size",str(size),image]) ,shell=True)
```

**Note:**

1. `str(size)` -  converting into string
2. `" ".join` - concatenating into `shell`-command

**But you can:**

```
subprocess.call(["truncate", "--size",str(size),image] ,shell=False)
```

Choose yourself what is suited for your needs.

Read  [Security Consideration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) before using `shell=True`

Comment: Thank you Alex, it worked. Yeh, sure will go with second option.

Answer (score 0):

use

`subprocess.call(["truncate", "--size",str(size),str(image)] ,shell=True)`

OR

`size= str(input('Please enter the size of the new image, in terms of Total Bytes =')).strip()
image= str(input("Enter the image file name =").strip()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the command like this

```
["truncate", "--size",size,image]
```

You can first create the command and store it in a variable like

```
command = 'truncate -s {} {}'.format(size, image)
```

Then use this command variable in the `subprocess.call` method.

Moreover give the absolute path of the image